# Semicolon or comma?

Tags: commas, semicolons

We are planning on having a staff meeting tomorrow**;** Friday, June 5th 11am-12 noon in our conference room.
Semi colon, or comma?

Comment: Semicolon is a full stop. Comma is not. Which do you hear there?

Answer (score 2):

Comma.  Semicolons are used when the sentence fragment can stand alone as a sentence - "Friday, June 5th 11am-12 noon in our conference room" cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually suggest neither.
What you need there is a [colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)): *" to inform the reader that what follows the colon proves, explains, defines, describes, or lists elements of what preceded it."*