# Replace em dash with semicolon

Tags: punctuation

There is the following sentence:

> I love the big and funny dog — Cooper.

This is absolutely fine to my understanding.

Now I was wondering if I could also *simplify* my sentence by writing it as follows.

> I love the big and funny dog; Cooper.

May I replace the em dash with a semicolon in this case?

*(Cooper is a name)*

Comment: Who or what is "Cooper"?

Comment: Cooper is a name

Comment: So is the big and funny dog called Cooper or is Cooper the one saying "I love the big and funny dog"?

Comment: It's at best very unusual to offset a renaming  appositive with a semicolon. A comma or brackets; perhaps a dash or ellipsis if you want a pause for effect.

Comment: @KillingTime the dog is called Cooper

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you have any other way to make the reader pause like with the dash?

Comment: The comma signals the usual slight pause in reading << I love the big and funny dog, Cooper. >> It's the typical way of showing non-defining (non-specifying) appositives. Contrast non-defining 'There's my sister, Anne' (= 'There's my sister, who is called Anne') with  defining 'There's my sister Anne' (as opposed to my other sisters). With your example, a non-defining reading is necessary. The dash or ellipsis may replace the comma, showing lengthening pauses (comma , dash , ellipsis). I suppose you _could_ put in a double ellipsis or full stop and fragment ('Cooper' already has a capital).

Comment: ... << I love the big and funny dog ... ... Cooper. >> or << I love the big and funny dog.  Cooper. >> But these are messy, some would say unacceptable. But the rules of punctuation are fairly loose and always in flux to some extent. Semicolons before fragments though are rare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ... correct to separate a complete sentence and an incomplete sentence {fragment} with a semicolon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508507/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-seperate-a-complete-sentence-and-an-incomplete-se/508529#508529) Or this?  [Semicolon or comma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250408/semicolon-or-comma)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the semicolon does not function like the em-dash in this case.

The semicolon is usually placed between independent clauses, or clauses that could function as standalone sentences ([Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html)):

> The upperclassmen are permitted off-campus lunch; the underclassmen must remain on campus.

In your example, *Cooper* is not an independent clause, so a semicolon would be infelicitous. *Cooper* could be considered nonessential information, further identifying "the big and funny dog." Instead, em-dashes usually stand in for commas, parentheses, or colons. In that case, one could use a comma instead ([Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html#settingoffnonrestrictiveinformation)):

> I love the big and funny dog, Cooper.

Another alternative would be a colon, which is occasionally used to add emphasis to the last word or phrase of a sentence ([Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html)):

> I love the big and funny dog: Cooper.

Finally, you could use parentheses, which are another way to set off nonessential or additional information ([Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/parentheses.html)):

> I love the big and funny dog (Cooper).